# How do I pass string with spaces to converterParameter?

Tags: c#, wpf

My sample code is below.

I want to pass 'Go to linked item' to `ConverterParameter` but I can't because the string has spaces.

```
Text="{Binding Value, 
        Source={x:Static local:Dictionary.Instance}, 
        Converter={StaticResource StringConverter}, 
        ConverterParameter=Go to linked item, Mode=OneWay}"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: how about `ConverterParameter='Go to linked item'`

Comment: thank you for your comment, but it's impossible also. T.T

Comment: Define a static resource for a string literal and use it.

Comment: i just tried passing it with a ' .... ..... ' and it worked

Comment: 'abcd efg hijk'  <-- it is worked! but, xaml file appear a message 'object reference not set to an instance of an object.' like error comments.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
Text="{Binding Value, 
        Source={x:Static local:Dictionary.Instance}, 
        Converter={StaticResource StringConverter}, 
        ConverterParameter='Go to linked item', Mode=OneWay}"
```

**Option 2**

If you want to use this in multiple places add a string resource.

```
<sys:String x:Key="GoToLink">Go to linked item</sys:String>
```

And pass the resource key.

```
ConverterParameter={StaticResource ResourceKey=GoToLink}}
```

Answer (score 9):

If your string has spaces then wrap it in single quotes, double quotes won't work; this is probably due to the fact that the entire text field is wrapped in double quotes and so using them again within the binding would incorrectly indicate closure.

```
Text="{Binding Value, 
    Source={x:Static local:Dictionary.Instance}, 
    Converter={StaticResource StringConverter}, 
    ConverterParameter='Go to linked item', Mode=OneWay}"
```

Comment: I like this answer best. putting the string in a resource or using a multibinding is un-necessary work.